# When I create a new Exception must I throw it or can I put it in a List instead?

Tags: java, exception

I've got a project where I have to parse formatted ASCII data. There is a possibility that the parser will identify when problems in the formatting (expected not found, unexpected data found). Normally, if I find a failure in something I throw an exception. This time however, I want to continue with the parse process, and store the parser error in the ending class. My question is, is it ok to create a new Exception and just store it in say a List rather than throwing it so not to stop the processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

- store a `List` of of problems (list of string messages, for example, or list of specific objects containing problem details)
- in the end, if the list is not empty, throw a custom exception that has the list

For example:

```
List<ParsingProblem> problems = new ArrayList<ParsingProblem>();
while (parsing) {
  ...
  problems.add(new ParsingProblem("some message", someRelevantValue));
}

if (!problems.isEmpty()) {
   throw new ParsingException(problems);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the name `Error` for this class. (Cause, judging from your constructor, I assume you're not referring to `java.lang.Error`).

Comment: @aioobe yesh, it's not java.lang.Error. I'll choose another name. Actually, I've see classes in this scenario to be called `Error` indeed, but perhaps it's not quite appropriate.

Comment: This is a pretty clear way to go I believe. Honestly, I should have thought of it myself, but for some reason had my head stuck on exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is, is it ok to create a new Exception and just store it in say a List rather than throwing it so not to stop the processing?

Yes.  That will work.  It is rather expensive though, because the Exception object captures all of the current thread's stack frames.  If you are not going to use the stack frames and not going to throw the exception, then you've done a lot of unnecessary work.  Unless there is a specific reason that you *have to* use an `Exception`, then a simple class to capture the error details is a much better idea.

However, there is a clever hack / trick you can use to make an exception object less expensive to instantiate.  If you look at the `Throwable` API, you will notice that there is a method called `fillInStackTrace()`.  The method is called by the `Throwable` constructor itself to capture the stack frames, and the implementation (in `Throwable`) does this in some native code.  However, this method is not `final`, so you can override it in an custom exception class to turn it into a no-op.

Voila!  A constructor that runs a lot faster!!  But of course, if you then need a stack trace for the exception, you are out of luck.  So I'd recommend using this hack / trick very sparingly.

Comment: You could overwrite `fillInStackTrace()` in order to avoid paying that cost always. I am not sure whether the constructors of `Throwable` call `fillInStackTrace()` at all.

Comment: @jmg ... I was getting there.

Comment: @Stephen C: You are not necessarily out of lack, when `fillInStackTrace()` is overriden. It is possible to call it with `super.fillInStackTrace()` from `public void reallyFillInStackTrace() { super.fillInStackTrace(); }`.

Comment: The method captures the stack frames for the current thread *at the time when the method is called*.  If you wait until you need to look at the stack trace before calling `super.fillInStackTrace()`, the chances are that you'll have lost a lot of information.

Comment: I don't believe that creating an Exception is that expensive to justify the overriding of `fillInStackTrace`. 1-probably fast since implemented in native code, and, 2-not called that often, only for parsing errors. It took about 1.5 seconds to create one million Exceptions (no parameters) with my *old* laptop; probably negligible when compared to the parsing process. (anyway, I would not use Exceptions {without throwing them})

Comment: @Carlos - it depends how deep the stack is when you throw the exception.  If you are 50+ calls deep (not uncommon) it might take considerably than that.  It also depends on how many of these things you plan to capture, and how long you intend to hang onto them.

Comment: Although this answer had the highest number of votes, I had to go with the other option, because (as I said in the comment to the accepted answer) it makes more sense as I do not really need to throw anything, mostly just log and track. For some reason I had it stuck in my head that I needed to use an Exception but in this case I think it is better if I don't.

Comment: @Stephen - correct. 1.5s for 3 calls deep, 5.8s for 50 calls deep stack; but I still think that is fast enough (less than 6 microseconds/Exception)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to abort processing (i.e. you can deal with the problem locally), you shouldn't use an exception. Creating an exception but not throwing it is not a very good idea (it is rather expensive, and it is not "mainstream", so it makes your code harder to understand and use).

It is better to just create e.g. an error message string and store it in the list of issues. Or, if you need to store more structured error info, create a custom class for it.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the language- or JVM-spec forces you to throw an `Exception`, you can handle it just the way you handle any other `Object` in Java. So yes, from this aspect it's perfectly fine to keep a list of `Exception` objects.

However, it's a rather unusual thing to do. I wouldn't call it a bad design, per se, but it's got somewhat of a strange smell to it.

Maybe you could avoid this problem, by creating a `Problem` and keeping that in a `List` (and adding such an object in your custom `Exception`).